# Difference between sample step and time step in LSTM (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to understand how the state progresses in an LSTM-layer. If I have the following code

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(4,2),stateful=False,batch_size=4))
yp=model.predict(np.array([    [[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]],
                               [[0,1],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0]],
                               [[0,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]],
                               [[1,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0]],
                              ]))
print(yp)
```

why do I not get yp[0,:,:] equal yp[:,0,:]?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is an array of `shape=(4,4,2)`, where the first 4 is batch size (4 samples), second 4 is time_step, and the last 2 is the input_dim of each time_step.

### Difference between sample step and time step in LSTM

Each sample can have multiple time steps, or even different time steps between samples is also valid.

### Why do I not get yp[0,:,:] equal yp[:,0,:]?

You need to understand that RNN block such as LSTM/GRU can **catch the dependency between time steps.** More concretely, there are different gates in LSTM that can carry the information from previous time step to current time step.
In your example, when the first sample `[[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]]` get into the model, the LSTM block actually **process the time step one after one, from [0,0]->[0,1]->...[1,1].** This is how forward-propagation in RNN is done. Therefore, the output state of different time step in different sample should be different.

Here is a [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-guide-to-lstms-and-gru-s-a-step-by-step-explanation-44e9eb85bf21) gives good explaination of LSTM/GRU with visualisation.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not understanding LSTM-cell itself. That is pretty well covered many places. However understanding how the state variables are passed from different instances of the cell is less clear. After doing some experiments and rereading the documentation, I believe I figured it out. Please see the post below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstood how the state variables are passed around. I had expected that the state variables were pass between sample steps. I have illustrated this in the image below. However that seems not to be that case. And if one reads the documentation carefully, it is stated how it works.

[image: My initial and wrong understanding of state flow]

I was fooled by the fact the with default initialization, an input of zeros does not change the state, so in my example y01=y10, y02=y11, y03=y12, and similar from sample 3 to 4.

My current understanding is that state variables are pass as in the illustration below.

[image: My current understanding]

This means that for each of the thee models below the output is the same.

```py
wts=[.5*np.ones((2,4)),.5*np.ones((1,4)),np.array([0,1,0,0])]

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(1,2),stateful=True,batch_size=1))
model1.layers[0].set_weights(wts)
yp1=model1.predict(np.array([[[0,0]]]))
yp2=model1.predict(np.array([[[0,1]]]))
yp3=model1.predict(np.array([[[0,0]]]))
yp4=model1.predict(np.array([[[1,1]]]))
print("model1:",np.hstack((yp1[:,0,0],yp2[:,0,0],yp3[:,0,0],yp4[:,0,0])))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(2,2),stateful=True,batch_size=1))
model2.layers[0].set_weights(wts)
yp1=model2.predict(np.array([[[0,0],[0,1]]]))
yp2=model2.predict(np.array([[[0,0],[1,1]]]))
print("model2:",np.hstack((yp1.reshape((-1)),yp2.reshape((-1)))))

model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(4,2),stateful=False,batch_size=1))
model3.layers[0].set_weights(wts)
yp=model3.predict(np.array([[[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]]]))
print("model3:",yp.reshape(-1))
```

> model1: [0.         0.16222607 0.12174767 0.46444273]
>
> model2: [0.         0.16222607 0.12174767 0.46444273]
>
> model3: [0.         0.16222607 0.12174767 0.46444273]

I hope this makes sense and will help others.

Thanks